# Pandas boolean slicing different results for same command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why does Example 1 give back NaN, while Example 2 doesn't?

Example 1:

```
data=DataFrame(np.arange(0,16).reshape(4,4),
               index=[list('abcd')],
               columns=[list('retz')])
data[data['t'] > 5]

    r   e     t   z
a NaN NaN   NaN NaN
b NaN NaN   6.0 NaN
c NaN NaN  10.0 NaN
d NaN NaN  14.0 NaN
```

Example2:

```
data2 = DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),
                     index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
                     columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
data2[data2['three'] > 5]

          one  two  three  four
Colorado    4    5      6     7
Utah        8    9     10    11
New York   12   13     14    15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first dataframe has a multiindex

```
data.axes
> [MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
              labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3]]), MultiIndex(levels=[['e', 'r', 't', 'z']],
              labels=[[1, 0, 2, 3]])]
```

Whereas your second doesn't:

```
data2.axes
> [Index(['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'], dtype='object'),
   Index(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], dtype='object')]
```

It's because you've wrapped `list('retz')` in another list, so it's interpreted as `[['e', 'r', 't', 'z']]`. If you want to have just a single index, you would just get rid of the brackets.

```
data=DataFrame(np.arange(0,16).reshape(4,4),
               index=list('abcd'),
               columns=list('retz'))
data[data['t'] > 5]
>     r   e   t   z
  b   4   5   6   7
  c   8   9  10  11
  d  12  13  14  15
```